# How can I use a try/except to check if an SQL query returns anything?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, try-except

I have written a small program which creates reports in a text file on the behaviours of students. However, I want my program to be able to break the -try- statement if no records are found. How do I do this?

I am writing it in Python and using sqlite3.

Comment: Please post your code. Maybe you can use `raise` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options, none require `try`:

1. for results that return only a single row, use [`cursor.fetchone()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone); this returns either the row, or `None` if there were no matches:

   ```
   result_row = cursor.fetchone()
   if result_row:
       # there was a result
   ```
2. for multiple rows, just loop over the cursor; if there were no results the loop will not throw an exception, just not iterate:

   ```
   for row in cursor:
       # do something with `row`
       # nothing will happen if there were 0 results
   ```

   If you wanted to detect if there were 0 results, you could set a flag variable:

   ```
   has_results = False
   for row in cursor:
       has_results = True
       # do something with `row`

   if not has_results:
       raise ValueError('No results for that query')
   ```
3. For a smaller set of expected results, you can use [`cursor.fetchall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall); this returns an empty list if there were no results:

   ```
   rows = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in rows:
       # do something with `row`
       # nothing will happen if there were 0 results
   ```

   Don't use this to process a large number of rows; just use option #2 for that.

   This option does give you the choice to do something else if there were 0 results:

   ```
   rows = cursor.fetchall()
   if not rows:
       raise ValueError('No results for that query')
   ```

If you **have** to use `try`, then provoke an exception. For options #1 and #3, all you need to do is indexing:

```
result_row = cursor.fetchone()
try:
    result_column = result_row[0]
except TypeError:
    # no result, `result_row` was `None`
```

or

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
try:
    first_row = rows[0]
except IndexError:
    # no results, `rows` was an empty list
```

For option #2, `next()` will throw a `StopIteration` if there is no next result:

```
try:
    first_row = next(cursor)
except StopIteration:
    # no results, nothing to iterate over
```